# Removing values from a matrix using coordinates in R

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have two different matrices of the same size, one with NA values and one without, such as:

```
mat=matrix(rnorm(9, mean=20, sd=10), nrow=3)
mat2=matrix(rnorm(9, mean=20, sd=10), nrow=3)
mat2[mat2<20]=NA

mat
             [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
     [1,] 21.67730 17.978427 17.24766
     [2,] 14.71108 16.970846 30.29543
     [3,] 28.65521  9.191494 18.83665

mat2
             [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
     [1,] 28.6093       NA 32.26887
     [2,]      NA       NA       NA
     [3,]      NA 20.19428 30.25038
```

I can identify the coordinates (rows/cols) of the NA values in `mat2` using:

```
which(is.na(mat2), TRUE)
```

How can I then use these coordinates to replace the same values in `mat` with `NA`? To produce:

```
mat
             [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
     [1,] 21.67730        NA 17.24766
     [2,]       NA        NA       NA
     [3,]       NA  9.191494 18.83665
```

Is this the best method to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matrices are represented as vectors internally (with information about dimensions), so you can do something like

```
mat[is.na(mat2)] <- NA
```

This creates a boolean vector indicating which elements of mat2 are `NA` and then assigns NA to these elements of mat.

Answer (score 3):

To simply replace those values with NA you can do this:

```
tmp <- which(is.na(mat2))
mat[tmp] <- NA
```